# Hash rocket vs colon in render json:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, hash

I am rendering a response to a `POST` request from a webhook. I just realized that when I `render json: thingee` and I log `thingee` it has hash rockets which are not valid json.

I've seen where people `puts` the hash and it looks fine, but that's not what I'm doing, I'm rendering a hash as JSON in response to a POST..

When rendered, my hash looks like this:

```
{"rates"=>[{"service_name"=>"Standard", "service_code"=>"f48",
"total_price"=>"390",},{"service_name"=>"Expedited", "service_code"=>"f34", 
"total_price"=>"640"}]}
```

But I need it to be valid JSON and look like this:

```
{"rates":[{"service_name":"Standard", "service_code":"f48",
"total_price":"390",},{"service_name":"Expedited", "service_code":"f34", 
"total_price":"640"}]}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to see a JSON representation of `thingee`, you can do `puts thingee.to_json`. `render json`  will return a JSON string to the browser, but when you do `puts thingee` you are seeing a string representation of a Hash object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry so much. Its perfectly fine.

In Ruby the hashrocket syntax needs to be used whenever you want to have a hash key that is not a symbol:

```
irb(main):002:0> { foo: 1, 'baz': 2 }
=> {:foo=>1, :baz=>2} # coerces 'baz' into a symbol
irb(main):003:0> { foo: 1, 'baz' => 2 }
=> {:foo=>1, "baz"=>2}
```

However when you pass the hash `render: { json: @foo }` the hash is passed to [JSON.generate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) which converts the ruby hash to valid JSON.

```
irb(main):006:0> JSON.generate({ "foo" => 1, "baz" => 2 })
=> "{\"foo\":1,\"baz\":2}"
irb(main):007:0> JSON.generate({ foo: 1, baz: 2 })
=> "{\"foo\":1,\"baz\":2}"
irb(main):008:0> { foo: 1, baz: 2 }.to_json
=> "{\"foo\":1,\"baz\":2}"
```